# Binding only some properties onto a grails domain object?

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a map like this:

`['var1':'property1',
 'var2':'3']`

and a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
   MyEnum var1
   int var2
   String var3
}
enum MyEnum{
   PROP1( "property1" )
   PROP2( "property2" );

   private final String variable;

   public MyEnum( String variable ){ this.variable = variable }
   public String getVariable(){ return variable }
}
```

I'd like to just try to bind `var1` and `var2` onto some existing object to get the validations, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `bindData` inside a controller. This method has optional arguments that allow you to explicitly state which properties should be included or excluded by the binding, e.g.

```
def map = ['var1':'property1', 'var2':'3']
def target = new MyClass()

// using inclusive map
bindData(target, map, [include:['var1', 'var2']])

// using exclusive map
bindData(target, this.params, [exclude:['var2']])
```

If you want to do this kind of binding outside a controller use one of the methods of `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils`, e.g.

```
/**
 * Binds the given source object to the given target object performing type conversion if necessary
 *
 * @param object The object to bind to
 * @param source The source object
 * @param include The list of properties to include
 * @param exclude The list of properties to exclud
 * @param filter The prefix to filter by
 *
 * @return A BindingResult or null if it wasn't successful
 */
public static BindingResult bindObjectToInstance(Object object, Object source, List include, List exclude, String filter)
```

Here's an example of using this method to perform the same binding as the "inclusive map" invocation of `bindData` above

```
def map = ['var1':'property1', 'var2':'3']
def target = new MyClass()
DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance(target, map, ['var1', 'var2'], [], null)
```

Comment: One huge caveat: If you bind a parent object and a container object separately, errors produced on the container object do not get rippled to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) method for this, so you can specify which properties you want to bind or which ones you don't.

Comment: Can I do this outside of a controller?

Comment: I've only used it inside controllers, but if you need to you might want to check the classes DataBindingUtils and BindDynamicMethod which are the ones that do all things related to the bindData method and see if you can use bindData outside of the controller. Not sure if there is an already a built-in solution or something easier for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
Map myClassMap = ['var1':'property1', 'var2':'3']
//You can use either of the following options
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myClassMap) 
myClass.properties = myClassMap
```

Comment: These options only work for GORM objects. A POGO doesn't have a constructor that takes a `Map` or a `setProperties(Map map)` method

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following syntax:

```
// update the var1 and var2 properties in the target
target.properties['var1', 'var2'] = params
```

As described in **Code Listing 4** of [Secure Data Binding With Grails](http://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails/)